# running program in high priority -> does not log anymore

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, logging

I have a project in visual C 2010 that needs real-time timing in high priority to eliminate stuff like hard disk maintenance and stuff.

I ran the .exe file of my project using start "" /high & start "" /realtime. 
(described here: https://superuser.com/questions/31802/starting-visual-studio-as-a-high-priority-process)

However, in the program I log the elapsed time and several other things, and running it this way stops the program updating the log files?

Note, for visual C, I found the .exe file in the debug folder with it's own separate set of log files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fflush() right after the logging statement so the data will be written to the disk.

see [Flushing buffers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450066/flushing-buffers-in-c)

Comment: Hi, so I put fflush(stdout); after my print to file statements, however I don't see why I should be doing that? It still doesn't log! :(

Comment: can you put a code snippet in your question? it could be due to other reasons.

Comment: Hi aaa, it runs and logs perfectly without my trying to set it to run high priority, so I don't know what code to put on.

Answer (score 0):

problem was, visual studio debug folder was write only. I was manipulating the .exe file in the debug, and that was why... take everything out into a new folder, and it should work!