# What is the exact meaning of "fflush(stdin)" in the following program?

Tags: c, pointers

I have searched and found a program for dangling pointers through some websites. I found one best program that executes perfectly in TC. But I cannot understand entire meaning of the program due my doubt in fflush(stdin). So please tell the meaning and other proceedings of the following program:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int *call(void);
    int main(void) {
      int *ptr;
      ptr = call();
      fflush(stdin);
      printf("%d", *ptr);
      return 0;
    }
    int *call(void) {
      int x = 25;
      ++x;
      return &x;
    }
```

Comment: No @Banthar. That question is not specific. But my doubt is specifically in the above program.

Comment: It's also UB because it returns and uses the address of an automatic variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no point in `fflush(stdin)` in general because it's undefined behavior (for a more detailed description of why see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450066/flushing-buffers-in-c/12450125#12450125), below the line break in the answer).

[`fflush()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) flushes buffers, when it's used in a contex like this, it's typically used in an attempt to flush the input buffer `stdin`. Thus there's nothing "pending" the buffer is in a clean state.

Specifically in this program there's no point to it at all. There are no input operations, thus it will do nothing<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>*Of course "undefined behavior" means anything could happen so it *could* do **something**, but should the platform support this and it does clear the buffer as expected, there will be no obvious effect to the code.</sup>

Comment: Well, as you said, it's UB, so it might very well do something (like nasal demons and so forth). But on platforms where `fflush(stdin)` empties the input buffered in the stream, it will indeed do nothing here.

Comment: @sepp2k - Ya know, I thought that after I wrote it... but then I thought "nah, no one will call me on that". ;)  yes, you are of course correct that it could do *something* as it's UB.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case `fflush(stdin)` is used to overwrite the contents of `ptr`. Any function is likely to overwrite dangling stack pointer. It looks like `fflush(stdin)` was chosen arbitrarily. I'm getting similar results with this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int* call(void);
int* dummy(void);

int main(){
    int *ptr;
    ptr=call();
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
    dummy();
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
    return 0;
}

int* dummy(void) {
    int x=0;
    return &x;
}

int* call(void){
    int x=25;
    ++x;
    return &x;
}
```

Comment: This code is broken like the original: UB due to use of the address of an object that has gone out of scope (via `&x` ).

Comment: @Jens I believe that's the point. It's supposed to demonstrate the dangers of dangling pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of fflush is to clean or flush the buffer generated due to its argument.for example

```
char ch [10];
scanf("%s",ch); // here scanf finishes taking input after tou pressed enter and that enter may still remain in keyboardbuffer
fflush(stdin); //flushes that enter which is in keyboard buffer
```

Now suppose if we write ch to a file using FILE pointer we will have desired output on file.
If you dont use

```
fflush(stdin);
```

And supose you want to write ch into a file then each each.time you write then it will be written in new line in file due to the effect of enter which is in keyboard buffer and is not desired.

Comment: This is undefined behavior and even if it wasn't, there are no input operations in the given code, so using `fflush` to clear remaining input would be absolutely pointless. I'm also not sure what you mean by "generated due to its argument" in your first sentence.

Comment: By "generated due to its argument" i mean that we use argument whose buffer we want to clean

Comment: And iam specifying function of fflush by my own example

Comment: You're *claiming* that `fflush(stdin)` has a certain behavior. However the standard does not define the behavior of `fflush` on input streams, so it is in fact undefined behavior. Note that `fflush(stdin)` will simply not do anything at all on many platforms, so your example won't do what you claim it does on those platforms.

Comment: But i have been taught that its behaviour is certain when something is there in the buffer and it will simply clean the buffer but when buffer is already empty then it may have UB

Comment: Then you have been taught wrong. Look at this: https://ideone.com/bvW2m5 . If `fflush` did what you say it does (on all platforms), the value of `next` should be `'e'` here, but it is `'\n'`.

Comment: Please give me a more example i am unable to understand it