# why my program fork function didn't run as expected

Tags: c, file, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE    *fp;
    int     pid;
    char    msg1[] = "Test 1 2 3 ..\n";
    char    msg2[] = "Hello, hello\n";

    if ((fp = fopen("testfile2", "w")) == NULL)    // create the file
        return 0;
    fprintf(fp, "%d: %s", getpid(), msg1);         // parent print the message1

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)                      // I fork a child process
        return 0;

    fprintf(fp, "%d: %s", getpid(), msg2);         // both parent and child print
    fclose(fp);                                    // and close

    return 1;
}
```

Here's the content of the "testfile2":

```
6969: Test 1 2 3 ..
6969: Hello, hello
6969: Test 1 2 3 ..
6970: Hello, hello
```

Comment: What *do* you expect it to do? Please add that information to your question.

Comment: Your if tags are not enclosed with `{}`

Comment: The program runs exactly as expected, it's just that your expectation is wrong.   What's really strange is that your program reports that it was successful only when `fopen` or `fork` fails, and reports failure in other cases.  (You should return `EXIT_FAILURE` or 1 when your program fails, and `EXIT_SUCCESS` or 0 when your program succeeds.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess: you would expect the output to be

```
6969: Test 1 2 3 ..
6969: Hello, hello
6970: Hello, hello
```

Right? So why isn't it like this? Well, I guess that the output of

```
fprintf(fp, "%d: %s", getpid(), msg1);
```

has not been flushed to the file at the point of time, when `fork()` is executed. So the output buffer is copied as well and that contains still

```
6969: Test 1 2 3 ..
```

So finally you what you got ;) I think this could be different, if you call `fflush(fp);` after the first `printff(...)`.

Check this nice [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450066/flushing-buffers-in-c) as well ...

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `fork()` correctly and your if tags are not enclosed.

## example

```
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t        */#include <sys/wait.h>  /* waitpid */#include <stdio.h>     /* printf, perror */#include <stdlib.h>    /* exit */#include <unistd.h>    /* _exit, fork */
int main(void)
{
   pid_t pid = fork();
 
   if (pid == -1) {
      // When fork() returns -1, an error happened.
      perror("fork failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else if (pid == 0) {
      // When fork() returns 0, we are in the child process.
      printf("Hello from the child process!\n");
      _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  // exit() is unreliable here, so _exit must be used
   }
   else {
      // When fork() returns a positive number, we are in the parent process
      // and the return value is the PID of the newly created child process.
      int status;
      (void)waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example from : http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)#Example_in_C