# Why is the input displayed after the enter key has been pressed?

Tags: c, stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* copy input to output */

main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();

    while(c != EOF)
        {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
        }

    return 0;
}
```

In the given code, the program displays the input character.
It reads every character one by one (into the variable 'c') and outputs the same read characters simultaneously. The program terminates when the EOF character is given as input.

When I ran the code in my IDE (Code::Blocks 16.01) and input a string,
eg: Hi! My name is C.\n

The output is displayed after '\n' and not simultaneously.
Isn't the output supposed to be as - "H**H**i**i**!**!**  M**M**y**y**  n**n**a**a**m**m**e**e**  i**i**s**s**  C**C**.**.**"?

Bold letters indicate the output.

Comment: After putchar() returns, the character are held in an internal buffer until the program exits/completes.

Comment: @ManmeetP And pressing 'enter' flushes out the buffer?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int  c;

    while ( (c = getchar ()) != EOF )
        putchar (c);

    return 0;
}`

Comment: Can you once try above program structure? and share output please.

Comment: Try `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: @ManmeetP I did. Isn't it just a compressed version of the same code? And the output is still the same. It takes the whole input into an internal buffer and then prints it after the newline('\n') character.

Comment: @AA Where exactly should I write the code `fflush(stdout);` ?

Comment: After `putchar` for example

Comment: @ManmeetP `stdout` not `stdin`. Here more https://stackoverflow.com/a/12450125/8918119

Comment: @AA Yes edit made, thx,

Comment: Right, as I suggested, _After putchar() returns, the character are held in an internal buffer until the program exits/completes_, fflush() is the method for it. USE: putchar(c); fflush(stdout);

Comment: See [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by default, **input from terminal is line-buffered**. So your program get a whole line after you press Enter.

To disable buffering in Unix & Linux systems, try this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int disableLineBuffer(void){
    struct termios term, oldterm;
    if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term)) return -1;
    oldterm = term;
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
    if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term)) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

In Windows, go and do this instead:

```
#include <windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DisableLineBuffer(void){
    HANDLE hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD mode;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(hInput, &mode)) return FALSE;
    mode &= ~ENABLE_LINE_INPUT;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hInput, mode)) return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Be sure to revert changes to the console before your program exits, or you may have trouble doing anything else in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

include:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
```

before your code in main insert:

```
struct termios term, term_orig;
if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term_orig)) {
        printf("tcgetattr failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
term = term_orig;
term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term)) {
    printf("tcsetattr failed\n");
    return -1;
```

}

after your code insert:

```
if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term_orig)) {
    printf("tcsetattr failed\n");
   return -1;
}
```