# Alpine Pipes Buffering

Tags: pipe, alpine-linux, buffering

I'm not really sure even what is the subject, initially I was struggling with `grep` with a suggestion the it is a root cause yet seems it is something related to pipes buffering or something

On `Alpine Linux v3.18` using `inotifyd` (fs changes tracking tool) in pipe produces a strange behavior
As a data source will be using same command `inotifyd - /tmp:ymndceDM` together with serial call similar to `echo 1 > /tmp/2.log`

Running a normal call as

```bash
# inotifyd - /tmp:ymndceDM | xxd
00000000: 6309 2f74 6d70 0932 2e6c 6f67 0a63 092f  c./tmp.2.log.c./
00000010: 746d 7009 322e 6c6f 670a 6309 2f74 6d70  tmp.2.log.c./tmp
00000020: 0932 2e6c 6f67 0a63 092f 746d 7009 322e  .2.log.c./tmp.2.
00000030: 6c6f 670a 6309 2f74 6d70 0932 2e6c 6f67  log.c./tmp.2.log
00000040: 0a63 092f 746d 7009 322e 6c6f 670a 6309  .c./tmp.2.log.c.
00000050: 2f74 6d70 0932 2e6c 6f67 0a63 092f 746d  /tmp.2.log.c./tm

# inotifyd - /tmp:ymndceDM | grep ''
c   /tmp    2.log
c   /tmp    2.log
c   /tmp    2.log
c   /tmp    2.log
```

produces pretty expected output

Yet if a pipeline is extended with extra commands an output stacks at a single line state as

```bash
# inotifyd - /tmp:ymndceDM | xxd | cat
00000000: 6309 2f74 6d70 0932 2e6c 6f67 0a63 092f  c./tmp.2.log.c./

# inotifyd - /tmp:ymndceDM | grep '' | cat
c   /tmp    2.log
```

regardless of serial incoming changes to subject file.

Using only `cat`s instead of `xxs` or `grep` works fine as well

Taking separately output from `inotifyd` into some log file and applying `cat changes.log` to the same (initially problematic) pipeline doesn't give described problems.

So please how this could be explained and resolved?

Thx

Trying to turn buffering (as my second suspection) off found suggestion to run commands in separate groups as

```bash
{ inotifyd - /tmp:ymndceDM; } | { grep ''; } | { cat; }
```

but that didn't really help

Edited:
Thanks to @programmerq answer bellow it turned out the buffering is the behavior of `xxd` it self in case it is down-streamed to a non tty.

I confirmed as well the same for `grep`. Actually trying

```
inotifyd - /tmp:ymndceDM \
  | xargs -n 1 -I {} \
   echo {} somenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoicesomenoi \
  | grep '' | cat
```

makes overflow the buffer each line and leads to a "realtime" output.

So the question now is how to disable buffering in more pure way?

`--line-buffered` is not supported for alpine and no other available options seem to help.

In my particular case I can see another workaround to multiply incoming lines by some factor as anyway the is a `uniq` below in the line. But this doesn't seem to be such a pretty solution. (e.g. Could the buffer size supposed to be constant)

Anyway is it possible maybe to fake `grep` somehow (with minimal code overhead) to make it think it is feeded down to tty?

Or what could be the resolution here to get a realtime stream of updates regardless chunk size?

Thx.

Comment: The `--line-buffered` argument is available on the grep included in the alpine `grep` package. The busybox `grep` applet that is available if you don't explicitly install the `grep` package doesn't support `--line-buffered`. Your trick to pack each line with extra input is probably your best bet for binaries that don't have a way to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate this behavior. Both the `xxd` busybox applet and the `xxd` binary from the `xxd` package had the same behavior.

I was able to show that it is indeed `xxd` that appears to be buffering output.

`inotifyd - /tmp/tmp.lKFfOk | tee foo | xxd | cat`

I can `tail -f foo` and see that the output from inotifyd seems to appear immediately. The `xxd` program seems to buffer things when its stdout isn't a tty.

If I force more activity in the directory that inotifyd is watching, the `|xxd|cat` pipe will output the new activity in chunks. If I kill the inotifyd process, the `|xxd|cat` pipe will flush all the remaining output.

Since other programs than `xxd` don't appear to buffer, this isn't a shell level pipe buffer that is happening. xxd does need to output things in whole lines, and it looks like it wants to have several lines of its output before it'll flush the buffer. (in my case 15 lines of xxd output appeared at a time)

I dug into the [xxd source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/xxd/xxd.c) a bit, and found that `xxd` uses `fflush()` when it writes its output.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68741792/4930423) to a question specifically about this `fflush` behavior, when the output is a tty, it will be *line buffered* by default. When xxd is piped to another program, that isn't a tty, so it uses a different buffering approach that causes the chunking behavior after the first line, as seen here.

When `xxd` receives an EOF (like when I killed the `inotifyd` to make it exit), the whole buffer will be flushed before `xxd` exits.

Comment: Oh @programmerq that's a great Idea to locate a buffering source this way. Thank you!! I confirmed the same for the `grep` command. So is there any solution to change the buffering behavior? Please see my updated post