# (How) is it true that the write() syscall stores data in the kernel?

Tags: c, system-calls, sys

In this stackoverflow question answer it is said that after sys call returns the data is in kernel. But isn't data output to the display and no more in kernel? Can someone explain in more detail? I can't comment in mentioned article because I don't have enough reputation.

From: [what is the different of using fflush(stdout) and not using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741707/what-is-the-different-of-using-fflushstdout-and-not-using-it)

> When the syscall returns, the data is in your kernel. But modern operating systems buffer this data as well. This is used to reduce the number of disk writes, reduce latency and other things. This buffer is completely independent of the FILE buffer inside your program.

Comment: That is relevant to physical storage media, which may have multiple buffers. After you call `fflush()` the OS guarantees that the data will (eventually) be placed in the storage medium, regardless of whether the C program terminates normally. If you have written data but the C program crashes, the output won't be posted if it was still buffered by the C library functions. That's what `fflush()` does. It ensures that output data is passed to the OS.

Comment: It's definitely not accessible to your program anymore. Theoretically after printf you can modify stream buffer, but after `flush()` you have no access to that data.

Comment: ...writing _to the display_ and writing _to a disk_, for example, are very different things; and different devices (or even differently-configured devices of the same type) have different levels of buffering sitting behind the syscall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For currently active interactive devices, such as displays, the kernel will quickly display the data.<sup>1</sup> The text you refer to in the other answer is about data being written to storage devices. The kernel may hold that data briefly, to combine it with other write operations. What is important here is that your program no longer has responsibility for the data. Even if your process exits or crashes after executing a `fflush`, the kernel will still write the data to storage. (The operating system can still crash, and data can be lost that way.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Depending on the operating system, it may be possible to stop terminal output by various means such as pressing <kbd>Control-S</kbd>, or a window may be currently covered by other windows and hence is not being updated.

Comment: Hmmm; is this true of unbuffered asynchronous write? Granted that's a rather extreme edge case, and only a few devices implement it.

Answer (score 2):

> But isn't data output to the display and no more in kernel?

As far as the OS is concerned, the display is just another file; `printf()` is basically just a version of `fprintf()` that assumes the output should go to `stdout`, i.e. the standard output stream. That stream normally is sent to the display, but in many operating systems you an also redirect it to a file or to the input of some other program.

What the answer you referred to is saying is that when you write to a file (or stream), the data you send is buffered by the `printf()` (or `fprintf()`) command, and calling `fflush()` triggers a context switch that moves the data from the buffer that it's in and into the kernel. From there, you don't have any control over what happens to it — it might be sent immediately to its destination or held in another buffer, but either way it'll eventually get to where it's meant to be.